# How to save slider value in to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

i create a js class and now i want to save a value of the slider (slider jquery UI) into textbox.

```
function Slider(name,orientation,range,disabled,min,max,value,valueLabel) {
this.name = name;
this.orientation = orientation;
this.range = range;
this.disabled = disabled;
this.min = min;
this.max = max;
this.value = value;
this.valueLabel = valueLabel;
this.setSlider = function() {
    jQ(""+name).slider({
        orientation: ''+orientation,
        range: range,
        min: min,
        max: max,
        value: value,
        change: function(event, ui) {
            jQ(valueLabel).attr('value', jQ(this).slider("value"));
        }
    });
}}
```

Can you help me? Why it's don't work?

valueLabel it's name of the label where i want to save value for example: #slider-value.

If i change a slider value i want get value of the slider. So i have to use change property.

Comment: Slider value means? value when user slides?

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this, use `slide` instead of `change`

```
jQ(""+name).slider({
    orientation: '' + orientation,
    range: range,
    min: min,
    max: max,
    value: value,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        jQ(valueLabel).val(ui.value); // .val() works if it's a textbox
    }
});
```

Your question is not quite clear but hope this will help you!